# Turn a live video podcast into a live audio only podcast?

Tags: audio, podcasts

Does a service exist (and can you tell me the names of one or more) that can turn a live video podcast into a live audio only podcast?

Comment: Are you looking to convert a live video stream on the fly to an audio only stream? Are you looking for a free service?

Comment: Yes, and yes. For the SE podcast.

Comment: Do you control the (video) source of the podcast or are you the consumer of a video broadcast and want to receive it as an audio-only stream?

Comment: I am the consumer of a video broadcast and want to receive it as an audio stream. It will be a live broadcast, so I'm sure that I will not be the ONLY subscriber for most durations. I do not want to host software on my own webserver or client for the purposes of this (or I would just open a client locally for the video and go on about my business).

Comment: Could you watch the video and create the audio at the same time? That is to point out that it is a live broadcast, so the assumption is you are watching it and then want to create an audio-only after that broadcast.

Comment: I want to create the audio stream on the fly from a live broadcast, so I can stream only the audio instead of streaming the video in it's entirety.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by the inactivity, no such application exists at the time of this writing.